# C++ | Reusing protected member of the Base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have a Base & Derived class:

```
class Base{
 private:
  int* _privateIntPtrB;
 protected:
  int* _protectedIntPtrB;
 public:
  //methods which use
  //_privateIntPtrB and _protectedIntPtrB

class Derived: public Base{
 private:
  int* _privateIntPtrD;
 protected:
  int* _protectedIntPtrB; //I am redeclaring this var
 public:
  //methods which use
  //_privateIntPtrD and _protectedIntPtrB
```

My question:
In the methods of the `Derived` class, does the Derived version of `_protectedIntPtrB` get used? (I think it does, but want to confirm).

If a method is not redefined by the `Derived` class, which version of the `_protectedIntPtrB`  will be used by a pointer to `Derived` class?

The reason I am asking - I want to initialize `_protectedIntPtrB` in the `Derived` class differently and want that version of the `_protectedIntPtrB` to be used in all the instances of Derived class.

Comment: Can't you just reuse the original one and assign it a different value in its constructor?

Comment: I always find questions of this kind hard to answer, despite doing C++ for over a decade now. Simply because the "correct" answer is to give whoever is attempting this a good hard slap: "I don't care what happens if you do this, *just don't do it!* :-D (See Wug's comment.)

Comment: It will use the one in the Derived class, but if you "want that version of the _protectedIntPtrB to be used in all instances of the Derived class" - do you mean static?

Comment: Just avoid `protected` attributes entirely and you'll save yourself a ton of debugging time figuring out why your invariants are being violated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the methods of the Derived class, does the Derived version of `_protectedIntPtrB` get used?

Yes, it hides the base class member and so an unqualified use of `_protectedIntPtrB` in the scope of `Derived` refers to `Derived::_protectedIntPtrB`. (The base class variable is still available, if qualified as `Base::_protectedIntPtrB`).

> If a method is not redefined by the Derived class, which version of the `_protectedIntPtrB` will be used by a pointer to Derived class?

The base-class variable. Data members of derived classes are not available from the base class.

> The reason I am asking - I want to initialize `_protectedIntPtrB` in the Derived class differently and want that version of the `_protectedIntPtrB` to be used in all the instances of Derived class.

Usually, the best way to make derived classes behave differently to their base classes is by overriding virtual functions. It would probably be better if you had a think about exactly what you want to achieve: work out what behaviour you want to modify, and encapsulate that in a virtual function.